# iOS: Making button not clickable except in edit mode. But enable=false not what I'm looking for

Tags: ios, button

I want to have a button with an image in it. The button is basically in "non-edit" mode just for display purposes and shouldn't change the color when clicking it. However in edit mode, it should lead to a new view where a user chan change the image. This all works. But at the moment the button remains clickable in non edit mode (however nothing happens), but the button should turn blue when clicking it…what can I do against that? Enabled = false makes it grayish which I don't want..the image should always look the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually customize the look of the disabled state:

```
[button setImage: image forState: UIControlStateDisabled]
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you want this:

button.userInteractionEnabled = NO;